# Add Alerts to WooCommerce Checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I need to add a couple of conditional alerts to the checkout process. I want to display a message with a link to a page that has full details. Here are the conditions:

1) alert customers if they are ordering within a certain time of year (longer handling time during holidays)

2) alert people if they are shipping to certain states (at a certain time 
of year)

3) alert people of longer handling time if stock quantity is low

How can I check these things and where do I put the code? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? That's a bunch of requirements without providing any information about what you've tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I'm new to WooCommerce and I'm wondering what my options are...

Answer (score 0):

For 1) alert customers if they are ordering within a certain time of year (longer handling time during holidays)

You could use the site wide notice in woocommerce settings.